# PHP - как убрать заголовки из ответа сервера?

Tags: php

После отправки post запроса мне приходит ответ:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx/1.3.9 Date: Fri, 14 Oct 2016 06:23:56 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 1948 Connection: keep-alive X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29-1~dotdeb.0 Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache Vary: Accept-Encoding {"data":[{"date":"2016-10-14 09:17:10","s1":"2","s3":"4","s5":"6","s7":"8","s9":"10","s11":"12","s13":"14","s15":"16","s17":"18","s19":"20"}
```

Как мне убрать всё, что идет до `{"data":[{"date":"2016-10-14 09:17:10","s1":"2","s3":"4","s5":"6","s7":"8","s9":"10","s11":"12","s13":"14","s15":"16","s17":"18","s19":"20"}`, т.е. мне нужно <s>с помощью регулярных выражений</s> как-нибудь убрать все заголовки.

Comment: видимо заменой от начала строки до фигурной скобки на фигурную скобку. `/^.*?{/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью чего вы делаете запрос? CURL? `file_get_contents`? Какой-нибудь веб-фреймворк. Всегда можно получить только тело ответа без заголовков.

Судя по формату, вам в ответ приходит обычный [JSON](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Можно декодировать ответ через [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php). В результате функция вернет вам обычный ассоциативный массив.

Comment: я делаю запрос с помощью cUrl и я пробовал json_decode но возвращается пустота, а вот если убрать заголовки то функция json_decode без проблем формирует массив. Как отключить именно получение заголовков от сервера? Ведь заголовки нужны в принципе, т.к. отправляются куки и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Запрос делается с помощью CURL. Для того, чтобы в ответе не было заголовков нужно добавить данную строку:

```
curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
```

Также вопрос решается при помощи регулярных выражений:

заменой от начала строки до фигурной скобки на фигурную скобку. /^.*?{/

Comment: Этот ответ не имеет ничего общего с вопросом. Вопрос про регулярные выражения, а ответ - про curl

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, при создании вопроса я хотел решить данный вопрос через регулярные выражения, но мне подсказали в комментариии, что если это через curl то можно по другому сделал, что собственно я и сделал. При том, что решение с регулярными выражениями также имеется, так что в данном вопросе два решения задачи.

Comment: В данном вопросе четко сказано, что нужно произвести обработку текста при помощи регулярного выражения. Про CURL в вопросе ничего нет. Как следствие, ответ про CURL - ошибочен. Мой минус на ответе именно про это.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, Вы совершенно правы, если смотреть на ситуацию прямолинейно, как робот. Но мы ведь не роботы. Да, в вопросе нет про CURL, но про CURL есть в первом ответе, и в этом ответе я нашел истинное решение и в дополнение дописал решение через регулярные выражения. Так что Уважаемый Дмитрий, для конечного пользователя данные ответы на вопрос являются куда более познавательными. Сайт ведь именно для этого предназначен, для обучения и обмена опытом.

Comment: И именно поэтому ответ, не связанный с вопросом - бесполезен.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev вопрос про то, как в php получить тело ответа, без заголовков. то, что топикастер при этом знает регулярные выражения - это проблема топикастера :)